# Cant set IPv6 Address on centos6

Tags: ipv6, iproute2

Im having this issue recently.

the iproute2 utility cant add a ipv6 address

```
/sbin/ip -6 addr add 2001:0db8:0:f101::1/64 dev eth0 

RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument
```

that ip is just copied from the examples I found online

in a fedora(20) machine works flawlesly but in this centos6 dont seems to work

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/default/disable_ipv6
0
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6
0
```

do I need a module?

I also tried with ifconfig and the result was the same

Comment: Are you absolutely sure the prefix is 48? It is usually 64

Comment: ah. I pasted a ip from google just to be sure that the ip is valid.  but checked the same ip from the example. letme edit that

Comment: Do you actually have an interface named `eth0`?

Comment: The command works on Ubuntu as well. I don't see anything wrong with it. I don't know any specific misconfigurations which would lead to that error message. Does the interface have any other IPv6 addresses assigned to it? Is there a link-local address?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I looked which error messages Ubuntu produces if the interface doesn't exist or has a too low MTU to run IPv6. Neither produced the same error message as the one in this question.

Comment: OK. the problem is that if you remove all you ipv6 address (even in your lo interface) later you cannot assign IPv6 on any interface except lo then you can again assign IPv6 freely... this seriously bugsme... this behavior is only present on my centos 6.2 machine, the fedora20 works as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry to respond to myself in such short time but this may help someone

```
ip -6 addr show
[root@ localhost main]#
```

no ipv6 on my system

```
ip addr add dev eth0 fe80::20c:29ff:fee3:d166/64
RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument
```

cannot assign ipv6, but if I do this

```
[root@localhost main]# ip -6 addr add dev lo 2001:0db8:0:f101::10/64

[root@buildhv main]# ip -6 addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436
    inet6 2001:db8:0:f101::10/64 scope global
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

lo got the ipv6,

and now

```
[root@localhost main]# ip -6 addr add dev eth0 2001:0db8:0:f101::20/64
[root@localhost main]# ip -6 addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436
    inet6 2001:db8:0:f101::10/64 scope global
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qlen 1000
    inet6 2001:db8:0:f101::20/64 scope global
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

eth0 got the ipv6
If you dont set LO in centos 6.2 you cant assign ipv6.
in the fedora box i can have ipv6 w/o lo

Comment: Why are you trying to put a global IPv6 address on the `lo` interface?!

Comment: just to demonstrate that it needs a IPv6 (sorry i dont have an ipv6 to test so  copy pasted one in my confined machine)

Comment: Don't mess with things. Leave the localhost address `::1` on the `lo` interface and save yourself a lot of trouble.

Comment: Got it, but my deep, my problem was the lack of any ipv6 on lo, and in my dictionary thats weird or a bug.